How to find top & bottom 3 values in a column with date google sheets?
I am making a P/L ledger for my trading account. Column A has Date , Column B day and Column C has the PNL.
       A        B     C
    3-Apr-2023  Mon 5200
    5-Apr-2023  Wed 8000
    6-Apr-2023  Thu -3000
    10-Apr-2023 Mon 0
    11-Apr-2023 Tue 2500
    12-Apr-2023 Wed 3200
    13-Apr-2023 Thu 2000
    17-Apr-2023 Mon 7200
    18-Apr-2023 Tue -6500
    19-Apr-2023 Wed -15500
    20-Apr-2023 Thu 6000
    21-Apr-2023 Fri 4500

I want a table which can show top 3 & bottom # values with date in excel / sheets.
Help me in making a table like this as i have attached.
Top 3 P/L   Date       bottom 3      P/L    Date
40000     3 May 23      -50000      4 April 24
30000     21 June 24    -40000      7 June 24
20000     1 March 24    -90000      14 Feb 24
        
        
         


Please [edit] your post to replace your images with text tables.

I deleted my answer since I saw that this is not the first time that you ignore comments about not using images.

Didn't knew images are such a big deal. sorry, i am not a regular user. Corrected.

To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas, the recommended method is to create a markdown table. You can use this tool to easily create the markdown_format & then add it to your question. Here's one example question you can maybe check out to get a clear picture on how to frame the question(with test data)

You can try the following formula (still untested):
=HSTACK(QUERY(A4:C, "select C, A where A is not null order by C desc limit 3"), QUERY(A4:C, "select C, A where A is not null order by C asc limit 3"))

References

HSTACK
QUERY


Error :
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AGG_IN_ORDER_NOT_IN_SELECT: MAX(C)

No, it works fine for me.
